# OCaml assertion failure

Tags: ocaml

this is my code and what it should be

### `prefixes: 'a list -> 'a list list`

`prefixes l` returns a list of all non-empty prefixes of an input list `l`, ordered from shortest to longest. There are no non-empty prefixes of an empty list.

### `powerset: 'a list -> 'a list list`

`powerset l` returns the powerset of the set of values in an input list `l` (the power set of a Set A is defined as the set of all subsets of the Set A including the Set itself). The order in the returned nested list (and each list element within) does not matter.

However, it keep gives me assertion failure for

```ml
assert (prefixes [1;2;3;4] = [[1]; [1;2]; [1;2;3]; [1;2;3;4]]);
assert (List.sort cmp (powerset [1;2;3]) = List.sort cmp [[1]; [1; 2]; [1; 2; 3]; [1; 3]; [2]; [2; 3]; [3]]);
```

What is problem with my code?

```ml
let prefixes l =
  let add_prefix acc x = match acc with
    | [] -> [[x]]
    | hd :: _ as lst -> (x :: hd) :: lst
  in
  List.rev (List.fold_left add_prefix [] l);;

let powerset l =
  let add_element_to_sets x sets =
    let with_x = List.map (fun subset -> x :: subset) sets in
    with_x @ sets
  in
  List.fold_right add_element_to_sets l [[]];;

let cmp x y = 
  if x < y then (-1) 
  else if x = y then 0 
  else 1 
in 
assert (prefixes [1;2;3;4] = [[1]; [1;2]; [1;2;3]; [1;2;3;4]]);
assert (prefixes [] = []);
assert (List.sort cmp (powerset [1;2;3]) = List.sort cmp [[1]; [1; 2]; [1; 2; 3]; [1; 3]; [2]; [2; 3]; [3]]);
assert ([] = powerset []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try your `prefixes` function:

```
# let prefixes l =
    let add_prefix acc x = match acc with
      | [] -> [[x]]
      | hd :: _ as lst -> (x :: hd) :: lst
    in
    List.rev (List.fold_left add_prefix [] l);;
val prefixes : 'a list -> 'a list list = <fun>
# prefixes [1;2;3;4];;
- : int list list = [[1]; [2; 1]; [3; 2; 1]; [4; 3; 2; 1]]
```

Yes, you reversed the whole list, but you never reversed the lists *inside* that list.

*Note that `cmp` is just reinventing the `Stdlib.compare` wheel.*

```
# let prefixes l =
    let add_prefix acc x = match acc with
      | [] -> [[x]]
      | hd :: _ as lst -> (x :: hd) :: lst
    in
    List.(
      l
      |> fold_left add_prefix []
      |> rev
      |> map rev
    );;
val prefixes : 'a list -> 'a list list = <fun>
# prefixes [1;2;3;4];;
- : int list list = [[1]; [1; 2]; [1; 2; 3]; [1; 2; 3; 4]]
```

Having made this change, only the last two tests involving `powerset` fail.

Testing `powerset`:

```
# [1; 2; 3]
  |> powerset
  |> List.sort compare;;
- : int list list =
[[]; [1]; [1; 2]; [1; 2; 3]; [1; 3]; [2]; [2; 3]; [3]]
```

Your test expected:

```
[[1]; [1; 2]; [1; 2; 3]; [1; 3]; [2]; [2; 3]; [3]]
```

And:

```
# []
  |> powerset
  |> List.sort compare;;
- : 'a list list = [[]]
```

Expected:

```
[]
```

Note that in all cases, when the output is sorted, the first element is the undesired `[]`. A simple expedient for removing this is to sort the list within the `powerset` function and then take the tail of the list.

```
# let powerset l =
    let add_element_to_sets x sets =
      let with_x = List.map (fun subset -> x :: subset) sets in
      with_x @ sets
    in
    List.(
      fold_right add_element_to_sets l [[]] 
      |> sort Stdlib.compare 
      |> tl
    );;
val powerset : 'a list -> 'a list list = <fun>
```

Having made this change, your last two tests now pass.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code. There's something wrong with your tests. `[]` is a prefix of every list, and it's also a subset of every set, so it should be included in the `prefixes` and `powerset` output (probably as the first element in both cases).

Comment: Note that the specification explicitly says "non-empty prefixes".

Comment: Thank you I find out that I need to be more specify for the output
So I add more results for power set and its working thank you!
assert (sort (powerset [1;2;3]) = sort [[1]; [1; 2]; [1; 2; 3]; [1; 3]; [2]; [2; 3]; [3]] || sort (powerset [1;2;3]) = sort [[];[1]; [1; 2]; [1; 2; 3]; [1; 3]; [2]; [2; 3]; [3]]);
      assert ([] = powerset [] || [[]] = powerset [])